# Riemann series theorem and infinite number of sums which sum to the same value

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Wikipedia:

"In mathematics, the Riemann series theorem (also called the Riemann rearrangement theorem), named after 19th-century German mathematician Bernhard Riemann, says that if an infinite series of real numbers is conditionally convergent, then its terms can be arranged in a permutation so that the new series converges to an arbitrary real number, or diverges."

Question of mine is:

> If $\sum a_k$ is some conditionally convergent series and $c \in (- \infty, + \infty)$ then is there at least a countably infinite number of permutations $\sigma_m(c);m=1,2,...$ such that $\sum a_{\sigma_m(c)}=c$ for every $c \in (- \infty, + \infty)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Let the sum of the first $n$ terms of your series be $s_n$.  Then the remainder of the series is conditionally convergent, so it can be rearranged to achieve a sum of $c-s_n$.  Choose one, and then move on.  For each $n$ this yields at least $n!$ permutations that give the desired sum, no more than $n$ of which can have been duplicated at a prior step.

Comment: This seems to me to be a nice answer but I do not understand "choose one", meaning to chose what? One term of the series? Or one permutation?

Comment: That gives countably many permutations that preserve the sum, but how about uncountably many permutations? I think that's OK, because given a convergent series, there are uncountably many permutations of its indices that preserve the convergence and the sum.

Comment: @YamMir Choose one permutation.  Whether there are uncountably many permutations that add to any given sum is not as clear to me.

Comment: @RobArthan I asked it on MO, [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/344985/riemann-series-theorem-and-uncountable-number-of-sums-which-sum-to-every-value). I think it´s not exactly what you meant but harder.